# difference between DLL wrapper and DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have no idea what is DLL wrapper. Could someone please explain me
1)  what is DLL wrapper?
2) how it is different from DLL ?
3) how to use it?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224869/Yet-another-DLL-wrapper-for-dynamic-loading for information on using a dll wrapper

Comment: I'd start with [this](http://bit.ly/XcBvzy) and take notes as I went.

Comment: @WhozCraig , I Did search on goggle but I failed to understand what  dll wrapper do ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a program uses a DLL, it goes like this:

- Application loads foo.dll
- Application calls function in foo.dll
- foo.dll executes function and returns value to application

With a wrapper DLL, this would happen:

- Application loads foo.dll (not knowing or caring that foo.dll is in fact the wrapper, and the original DLL has been renamed to foo_original.dll)
- foo.dll loads foo_original.dll
- Application calls function in foo.dll
- foo.dll forwards the call to foo_original.dll
- foo_original.dll executes function and returns value to foo.dll
- foo.dll returns value to application

This gives the DLL wrapper an opportunity to inspect/log all calls made by the application to the original DLL, as well as a chance to modify data being passed between the two.

Answer (score 3):

DLL wrapper calls another dll to provide required functionality. It may or may not provide its special API for simplicity or compatibility reasons.
[This is a tutorial](http://www.svenberra.net/wraptutor.zip) that shows how to make a wrapper DLL.
In this specific tutorial some of the classes from DirectX 9 are wrapped and used to render a teapot inside the Blitz3D window.

Comment: +1 Another dll *or static library*. One of the strongest uses of a DLL-wrapper is to single-module-home a static library that expects to be the only copy of itself in a process address space, yet is used by multiple DLL's and maybe the root EXE as well. Burying it in a single DLL and exposing the parts you need to the other modules ensures this can happen.