# DllCalls in a vbscript

Tags: vbscript, autohotkey

I would like to have a simple vbs script which runs on every Windows PC without additional apps and tools.

Below is a short script written in [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/):
A text string is extracted from a file and added as resource in an exe file by dllcalls.

Can this be reproduced in a simple way in vbs?

```
ExeFile = MyExe.exe
ScriptF = Script.txt
FileRead, Script, %ScriptF%

VarSetCapacity(Bin, BinScript_Len := StrPut(Script, "UTF-8") - 1)
StrPut(Script, &BinScript, "UTF-8")

Module := DllCall("BeginUpdateResource", "str", ExeFile, "uint", 0, "ptr")

DllCall("UpdateResource", "ptr", Module, "ptr", 10, "str", ">MY SCRIPT<"
                        , "ushort", 0x409, "ptr", &BinScript, "uint", BinScript_Len, "uint")
DllCall("EndUpdateResource", "ptr", Module, "uint", 0)
```

Comment: There is no simple way, but it's possible to create VBScript, which copies to temp folder wscript.exe, extracts there embedded dynwrap.dll and additional .manifest files for them created via regsvr42 to set dlls dependencies for further usage without registering dynwrap and other dlls, restarts itself via copied wscript.exe, registers dll functions like VBA's Declare, and delegates control to the user code part. That's it, in outline.

Comment: @omegastripes what's `regsvr42` you mean `regsvr32.exe` right? But how would work without building a COM wrapper?, you completely lost me sorry.

Comment: @Lankymart I mean exactly [regsvr42 to create .manifest files](https://www.google.ru/search?q=regsvr42+manifest).

Comment: @omegastripes wow, you learn something new everyday great link.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is No.

---

VBScript can only call DLLs that are exposed through [COM *(Component Object Model)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) and referenced in VBScript via the function [`CreateObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcw63t7z(v=vs.84).aspx).

Here is an example of VBScript calling an external library;

```vb
Dim dll: Set dll = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Call the CreateFolder() method from FileSystemObject object in the Scripting Library.

dll.CreateFolder("C:\test")
```

Although this is technically a built-in component *(part of the Scripting Runtime)* it demonstrates the process and is housed in an external library *(`scrrun.dll`)*.

In this case though as according to the documentation

> <sup>From [AutoHotKey Reference - DllCall()](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DllCall.htm)</sup>
>   *DllFile may be omitted when calling a function that resides in `User32.dll`, `Kernel32.dll`, `ComCtl32.dll`, or `Gdi32.dll`. For example, `"User32\IsWindowVisible"` produces the same result as `"IsWindowVisible"`.*

the script is calling Windows System DLL function calls that are unlikely exposed to COM. The only option would be to write a COM [DLL wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15132542/692942) for the Windows System DLLs.

Comment: Thank you very much, Lankymart. So it is not possible to do in VBS the same as in VB? I found e.g. this example:  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?631126-how-to-update-resdata&highlight=updateresource . (Offtopic here: Do you see another approach to implement this functionality in a kind of script which is running on every Windows PC?)

Comment: @newbieforever Like I've said you can't call system functions like the ones in `kernel32.dll` from within VBScript without putting work into writing a COM DLL wrapper in something like C++, C#, VB.Net etc then calling that through `CreateObject()` in VBScript.

Comment: I am a nuisance, I know: No hint to my offtopic question above?

Comment: @newbieforever lol, no not at all just would be repeating what I already wrote. :D As for the off topic question, probably needs another question as  would need more detail about what you are trying to accomplish.